# SSL error: OCSP_basic_verify() failed

Tags: ssl, logging, nginx, configuration, certificate

**My log file (error.log) got spammed by this error:**

```
2016/10/08 09:50:06 [error] 1014#1014: OCSP_basic_verify() failed 
(SSL: error:27069065:OCSP routines: OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:
Verify error:self signed certificate in certificate chain) while requesting certificate 
status, responder: ocsp2.globalsign.com
```

I can't really find the solution of this issue, could you help me?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (NGINX + php7.0-fpm)

**Part of my example.conf file:**

```
server {

  server_name example.com;
  charset UTF-8;
  listen  443  ssl http2;
  ssl on;
  ssl_verify_client    off;
  ssl_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/example/example.crtca";
  ssl_certificate_key "/var/www/httpd-cert/example/example.key";
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;
  resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
  resolver_timeout 10s;
  ssl_trusted_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/example/example.crt";

  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_timeout 1h;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:16m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MD5:!EXPORT:!EXP:!LOW:!SEED:!CAMELLIA:!IDEA:!PSK:!SRP:!SSLv:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';

  ...
```

Why am I getting this error? My certificate is not self signed

Answer (score 0):

> ssl_trusted_certificate "/var/www/httpd-cert/example/example.crt";

This setting should contain the CA which is trusted for issuing the OCSP response, i.e. usually the issuer CA. My guess is that your file does not contain the necessary CA and that's why it cannot validate the OCSP response as requested by using `ssl_stapling_verify on`.

See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_trusted_certificate) for more information about this setting.

Comment: Note: It is always a good practice at similar situations to check the certificate file(s) not to contain any "leftover" special characters, new lines (for example between certificates) etc., and - if it's possible - use restarting nginx to immediately stop all worker processes (old ones can still send obsoleted errors).